# Getting error while editing or making template of cart in 2checkout

Tags: templates, shopping-cart, 2checkout

I want to customize the "Interface template" (shopping cart) of 2checkout.com. I don't know what's the issue but I am getting the error "Oh snap! Change a few things up and try again.".

Please guide me if someone recently faced that issue and rectified it successfully.